# wget HTTP Error 403: Forbidden in Python when trying to download pdf

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I wrote code that downloads data from the Florida Department of Emergency Management website. For months the code has worked just fine. However today when I run it I get the error below. I even tested just the wget with the direct link to one of the files and still got the same error. I've double checked my user agent. I modified my header. If I download a file from the site using wget without running my selenium-based script I can download them individually. I'm guessing the site is blocking me because it recognizes me as a bot, but I'm not sure how. Can anyone explain why this is still happening and what I can do to fix the issue?

USER AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36

## CODE:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path,options=chrome_options)

print('Starting Data Download')
link_counter = 0
download_counter = 0 
link_n = len(result_full) -152
download_list = []
for links in result_full:
    if links.text.find('Data Report') > 0:
        link_url = links.get_attribute('href')
        filename = wget.filename_from_url(link_url)
        if not os.path.exists(f'{pdf_output_path}/{filename}'):
            wget.download(link_url, out = f'{pdf_output_path}')
            download_counter += 1
            download_list.append
            print("Downloading", links.text)
        link_counter +=1
        print (f'{round((link_counter)*100/link_n,2)}% Complete')
print('Download of New Files Complete')
print(f'{download_counter} Files Created')
```

## ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-3aafa377b505> in <module>
      9         filename = wget.filename_from_url(link_url)
     10         if not os.path.exists(f'{pdf_output_path}/{filename}'):
---> 11             wget.download(link_url, out = f'{pdf_output_path}')
     12             download_counter += 1
     13             download_list.append

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wget.py in download(url, out, bar)
    524     else:
    525         binurl = url
--> 526     (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
    527     filename = detect_filename(url, out, headers)
    528     if outdir:

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

E:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have an error 403, that means you dont have permission, according to the status codes. which you can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

You might need some kind of authentication on the website, you might need to post some credentials through your app and then try to download.

Comment: That is not the problem here. The data is publicly available and free to download. No authentication required.